# Can Audible bookmarks be exported

Tags: audible

I have hundreds of audio books on Audible and many have bookmarks/notes recorded in the Audible app.  I'd like to export them to make them more useable.  That is, so I know which books contain notes and what they cover.  Exporting them to a spreadsheet would be ideal but at this point any format is better than nothing.